# Como calcular hora y minutos en base a minutos

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con respecto a la hora y los minutos. Tengo un programa en python. El cual al usuario se le pide ingresar los minutos. Y eso se debe convertir a hora y minutos. Los segundos no son tomados en cuenta, es decir no se pide al usuario ingresarlo.

Esto llevo ahora.

`dato= int(input("Ingrese los minutos: "))`

`hora = dato/60`

`minutos = (segundos-hora*3600)/60`

Normalmente así se obtienen los minutos. Pero en este caso **no** se pedirá los segundos al usuario. Por lo que pensé en quitar eso y dejarlo así:

`minutos = (hora*3600)/60`

Pero luego de probar claramente no funciona. Porque tomando un ejemplo. Si el usuario ingresa, como dato.
El numero 305. Eso es 5 Horas con 5 minutos. Con el primer calculo se logro obtener las horas pero los minutos no. Quisiera saber en que estoy mal. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Necesitas una división de números enteros. Con Python 3 seria `hora = dato // 60` y `minutos = dato - hora * 60`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, `hora = dato/60` te da las horas en formato decimal, para el ejemplo que pones sería `5.083333333333333`. Te interesa solo la parte entera, las decimal son los minutos restantes.

Como te quedas con todo, `minutos = (hora*3600)/60` no hace más que invertir la operación anterior, por lo que obtienes de nuevo 305...

Puedes hacer algo como:

```
dato = int(input("Ingrese los minutos: "))
hora = dato // 60
minutos = dato - (hora * 60)
```

El operador `//` es la división entera, que retorna solo la parte entera de la división, 5 en el ejemplo que das. Alternativamente puedes usar el operador módulo `%` (`dato % 60`)para calcular los minutos, en vez de calcular el resto "manualmente".

Si puedes usar `divmod(a, b)`, retorna la parte entera y el módulo (resto) de dividir `a` entre `b`, simplemente:

```
dato = int(input("Ingrese los minutos: "))
hora, minutos = divmod(dato, 60)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto amigo

```
dato= int(input("Ingrese los minutos: "))

hora = dato//60  # el operador // obtiene la parte entera de la división
minutos = dato % 60  # el operador % nos da el resto de la división (los minutos)

print('Hora: ', hora, ' minutos: ', minutos)
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo realizaría así, pero te indico que llevo solo un par de meses con python seguro hay alguna forma mas limpia no se si usando format en los float...

```
### minutos a horas y minutos

time = float(input("Input time in minutes: "))
hour = time%60
minutes= (time//60)
print("It´s",int(hour),"hours and", int(minutes),"minutes.")
```